# Can I add a file/application to an Ubuntu boot disc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Noob here:

For safety reasons, I want to run a certain application from a Live Disc while not connected to the internet.

Can I add this application to the Live Disc ISO?  Or would I have to run it from USB?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- Ubuntu makes this comparatively simple with [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) or[InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Installing_extra_packages_in_your_preseed_file). See [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso) for the answer to a similar question.
- You may find that there is already a live ISO with the desired application. For example, [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php), which cannot run from the partition being imaged, offers a "small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for imaging and cloning"... no need to reinvent the wheel.
- It may also be possible to add an additional partition to the boot device, put the application packages there and mount that partition after booting. This is an easy way to include a Windows application if it can run in wine.